# Embeddings and connected sum

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a compact connected oriented smooth $m$-manifold. For any compact connected oriented smooth $m$-manifold $W$, consider their well-defined *[connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum)* $$X \# W.$$

I wanted to ask two basic questions about this operation:

1. Is there always a smooth embedding from $X$ to $X \# W$?
2. Can we realize $X$ as a submanifold of $X \# W$?

**EDIT:** Assume that $X$ or $W$ not diffeomorphic to $S^m$ since it gives the identity element for connected sum operation.

Comment: What if you take $X=S^2$ (two-dimensional sphere) and $W=T^2$ (two-dimensional torus)?

Comment: I excluded this case in my mind since it gives the identity element for connected sum operation.

Comment: Did you have a look at the case $T^2\sharp T^2$?

Comment: Would like to write down a complete answer if you have some simple counterexamples in your mind?

Comment: You didn't show any argument where you got stuck, so I'm suggesting some examples to look at before trying to answer a general question.